# What units does curl use for bandwidth?

Tags: curl

`curl` on the command-line displays progress like this:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  8 1000M    8 85.2M    0     0    57k      0  1:06:13  0:05:38  1:00:35   47k
```

The speed displayed in this example is `47k`. But what does this mean? Is this:

- 47KiB, that is 47 * 1024 bytes
- 47kB, that is, 47 * 1000 bytes
- 47kb, that is, 47 * 1000 bits (bits are often used to measure speed)

And is it:

- per second
- or per minute?

Comment: Similar question for wget: http://superuser.com/q/184331/90668

Comment: possible duplicate of [How accurate is CURL's 'current rate' in the progress meter?](http://superuser.com/questions/884350/how-accurate-is-curls-current-rate-in-the-progress-meter)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

#### What units does curl use for bandwidth?

According to the [source code](http://opensource.apple.com/source/curl/curl-83.1.2/curl/lib/progress.c) it is `KiB per second`.

---

Here you can see the definition uses `1024` and not `1000`

```
/* The point of this function would be to return a string of the input data,
   but never longer than 5 columns (+ one zero byte).
   Add suffix k, M, G when suitable... */
static char *max5data(curl_off_t bytes, char *max5)
{
#define ONE_KILOBYTE  CURL_OFF_T_C(1024)
#define ONE_MEGABYTE (CURL_OFF_T_C(1024) * ONE_KILOBYTE)
#define ONE_GIGABYTE (CURL_OFF_T_C(1024) * ONE_MEGABYTE)
#define ONE_TERABYTE (CURL_OFF_T_C(1024) * ONE_GIGABYTE)
#define ONE_PETABYTE (CURL_OFF_T_C(1024) * ONE_TERABYTE)

...

}
```

Here you can see the calculation is done in ms and then divided by `1000` to get seconds.

```
  /* Calculate the average speed the last 'span_ms' milliseconds */
  {
    curl_off_t amount = data->progress.speeder[nowindex]-
      data->progress.speeder[checkindex];

    if(amount > CURL_OFF_T_C(4294967) /* 0xffffffff/1000 */)
      /* the 'amount' value is bigger than would fit in 32 bits if
         multiplied with 1000, so we use the double math for this */
      data->progress.current_speed = (curl_off_t)
        ((double)amount/((double)span_ms/1000.0));
    else
      /* the 'amount' value is small enough to fit within 32 bits even
         when multiplied with 1000 */
      data->progress.current_speed = amount*CURL_OFF_T_C(1000)/span_ms;
  }
```

Comment: I had to look this up, so hopefully this saves someone the effort: kiB is a [kibibyte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kibibyte) and you can search sites [like this one](http://www.convert-me.com/en/convert/data_transfer_rate/?u=kibibyteps&v=108%2C000) to convert it to other units.

Comment: It is being multiplied rather than divided :)